# Javascript function scope and execution context

Tags: javascript, scope

I have some functions and variables:

```js
function b() {
  myvar = 1;
  console.log(myvar);
  a();
}

myvar = 5;
a();
b();
a();

function a() {
  console.log(myvar);
}
```

The console log output is: `5, 1, 1, 1`. Why is the last a() call getting "1" as output and not "5" ? Because I thought a() is called from global context, and this global context has myvar=5 as its outer (one level up) variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no *local* variables in this code - every variable name reference is a reference to a global variable, so whenever a reassignment happens, that global variable will be reassigned.

If `b` reassigned a *local* variable named `myvar`, you'd be correct, for example, if `myvar` inside `b` was a *parameter*, or declared with `var/let/const` inside `b`:

```js
function b() {
  // next line has "var",
  // indicating that whenever the following variable name is used inside this function
  // it'll be referring to a local variable, not the global `myvar`:
  var myvar = 1;
  console.log(myvar);
  a();
}

myvar = 5;
a();
b();
a();

function a() {
  console.log(myvar);
}
```

Comment: ok thanks you are correct, I forgot to declar myvar with "var" in b()... didn't know javascript was that delicate.. those details really matter ;)